# How do I manually reorder program tabs on the bottom panel taskbar of Centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos

I would like to be able to reorder the program tabs found at the bottom panel, the taskbar of my Centos desktop. Similar to how you can reoderder tabs when using Firefox, I would like to have this functionality for the programs I open.

Comment: This seems to be more like a GNOME Desktop or KDE Desktop related question than a CentOS specific question? GNOME/KDE runs on Debian, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using KDE on Centos7, so I can explain it only on KDE.

(Right click on task bar) -> Task Manager Settings -> Sorting: Manually -> Apply

[image: Task Manager Settings]

And then, you can drag and drop a task on task bar to reorder as you wish.

Comment: Is there any other way to get to the "Task Manager Settings" as I can't seem to right click on the task bar. I looked into the "Settings" application as well as the "KDE System Settings" application and cannot seem to find it there.

Comment: Nvm. I just check my system using the command 'echo $DESKTOP_SESSION' and it outputs gnome-classic so I think this is why I cannot right-click on the taskbar but why would I have an application called KDE System Settings if I'm on gnome?

Comment: My desktop is KDE and yours are Gnome classic. They may have different taskbars. Currently I don't have gnome classic desktop and don't know it support manual sorting. If I find how to set it manually, I will add a comment here.

Comment: I set Gnome-classic and tried to find how to reorder tasks, but I couldn't find it. I think Gnome-classic may not support it. If you really want it, I suggest that you should change your desktop manager such as KDE.